# How Do I hide O365 Menu?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, menu

[image]

What is best way for me to hide 0365 menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would like to hide it but some CSS will work.

If it's just for a single page you could use a Script editor webpart if that's available. Otherwise add the CSS to a text document and use it as an alternate CSS URL for the site.

Be aware of the classes used in the first CSS that is named *..-header**16***. This indicate that Office 365 is now running on SharePoint 16 so this might change in the future or anytime Microsoft applies any changes to Office 365.

For the menu, Office 365 and SharePoint:

```
<style type="text/css">
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-leftAlign {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Or the menu only:

```
<style type="text/css">
.o365cs-base .o365cs-navMenuButton {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you are really really worried about that 16 notation and want to allow for future changes (by Microsoft), you can always write: ``[class*='o365cs-nav-header']``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I learned something new related to CSS today to then! :)

Comment: Do I need to delete old css is calling 0365 menu to be called

Comment: @user3161390 No you should not have to do that. If it won't work you can use the !Important property as a last option. https://appendto.com/2016/04/css-important-rule-how-to-use-it-correctly/?nabw=1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.se%2F

Comment: 2 in one day, Christoffer... Please learn about CSS Specificity before destroying styling with ``!important``  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - Mentioned "as a last option"/added some read-worthy material on do's and don't. So it's more a matter of to share what i know or just don't answer at all. It's always a positive thing with having a dialogue related to an answer/question on to solve something  in the best/correct way. If i mastered CSS i guess i would been busy doing something else then spend some time here now and then.

Comment: Sorry, Personal vendetta against ``!important`` Have had to clean up too many projects.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman No problem, i stopped using it months so i consider myself enlightened. However for quick-fixes / one a single page or for a single element (code stored in one location) i think it's Okay if you don't have the time to take a deeper dive into more advanced CSS. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to hide just the above 3 that you have posted in the screenshot, you can use the below css:

```
button#O365_MainLink_NavMenu,
#O365_MainLink_Logo,
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-brandingText {display:none;}
```

Add it in your css code or inside `<style>` tag. This works in my tenant, but the selectors could be different in your tenant. You should press F12 and inspect the elements to find out your selectors. The value of selectors **might** change after some days whenever MS pushes some update, so i would not recommend that you hide these , instead it would be better if you educate your end users about this. Also you can customize your entire suite bar to reflect a better branding.

[Customize the Office 365 theme for your organization](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Office-365-theme-for-your-organization-8275da91-7a48-4591-94ab-3123a3f79530?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)